# How to get child product id of configurable products in cart page?

Tags: magento2

I tried,
Attribute name is **net_details**

```
 $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
 $details = json_encode($net_details);
 $quoteItem->setNetDetails($details);
```

In quote item table value gets stored in product_type = configurable of respective products

My requirement is to store the value where product_type = simple

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach ($cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
    if ($option = $item->getOptionByCode('simple_product')) {
        $productId = $option->getProduct()->getId();
    }
    $productIds[] = $productId;
}
```

Comment: What if there are mixers of Simple and Configrable?